# How to delete session cookie in Postman?

Tags: postman

I am testing my API in Postman and am having trouble simulating a **log out**.

If I do a call to delete the session cookie,
[image: postman request]
the session cookie is **still there** afterwards, and I'm still able to access routes that require authentication.

The route handler on the server is:

```js
  server.route({
    method: 'DELETE',
    path: '/sessions/_current',
    handler: function(req, reply){
      req.auth.session.clear();
      reply({}).code(204);
    }
  });
```

<sup>This is Node.js with Hapi but it shouldn't matter.</sup>

Is there a way to **delete all the cookies** in Postman or **certain cookies manually**?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Manually deleting it in the chrome browser removes the cookie from Postman.

In your chrome browser go to `chrome://settings/cookies`

Find the cookie and delete it

**Edit:**
As per Max890 comment below (in my version of Google Chrome (ver 63)) this is now
`chrome://settings/content/cookies`
Then go to "See all cookies and site data"

**Update for Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88**

chrome://settings/siteData?search=cookies

Comment: I cleared cookies from chrome and cmd line also, but still postman has session data.

Comment: this works in the "newish" postman stand-alone app as well. look no further!

Comment: This will only work if you have installed postman interceptor extension and enabled it otherwise you will get cookies options below send button in postman.

Comment: In 2017, the link is now chrome://settings/content/cookies

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 168):

Postman 4.0.5 has a feature named *Manage Cookies* located below the *Send* button which manages the cookies separately from Chrome it seems.

[image]

Comment: There is a cookies button if you move 2 c.m down and 1 c.m right from the bottom right edge of blue send button :)

Comment: @utkarshdubey nope

Comment: As far as I know, this is only available in the "native app" rather than the Chrome extension, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: In the current version of Postman standalone (v5.5.0), this 'Cookies' link is directly under the Send and Save buttons. Screenshots are below by @moplin

Comment: Aww this is great, i was struggling to find why my creds were being stored when requesting a new oAuth2 access token, this has helped me be able to clear the session details and prompt for login again!

Answer (score 22):

As @markus said use the "Cookie Manager" and delete the cookie.
[image]

If you want to learn how to set destroy cookies in postman, You should check the Postman Echo service https://docs.postman-echo.com/

There you will find complete explanation on how to Set, Get and Delete those cookies.

Check it on : https://docs.postman-echo.com/#3de3b135-b3cc-3a68-ba27-b6d373e03c8c

Give it a Try.

Answer (score 11):

Note that this answer applies only to the **standalone Postman UI** and not the Postman app/add-on for Chrome.

**How to clear the cache in Postman (so that you are required to log in again when requesting a token, for example):**

- navigate to View: Show DevTools
- navigate to the Application tab, then the Clear Storage view in the left menu
- deselect all choices except Cache Storage, then click on ‘Clear site data’
- restart Postman
- you should now be prompted to log in again when requesting a new token

Comment: I just cleared the global storage and it deleted all postman collections, configurations etc. You might want to add a warning to the answer!

Answer (score 9):

In the **Native** Postman app there is "Cookie manager", so that is not a problem at all,

**But in the Postman extension for Chrome there is not**

So the solution is just in the installing native Postman

[Postman for Linux, Mac & Windows](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)

Answer (score 6):

Is the Postman Interceptor enabled? Toggling it will route all requests and responses through the Chrome browser.

Interceptor - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture
Cookies documentation - http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/

Comment: Yes. I tested both with the interceptor on and off and the cookie is still there.

Comment: Worked for me with Postman 4.7.1 (installed Interceptor, re-run Postman and activated interceptor within Postman)

Answer (score 5):

new version of postman app has the ability to do that programmatically in pre-request or tests scripts since 2019/08

see more examples here: [Delete cookies programmatically · Issue #3312 · postmanlabs/postman-app-support](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312)

## clear all cookies

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.clear(pm.request.url, function (error) {
  // error - <Error>
});
```

## get all cookies

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.getAll('http://example.com', function (error, cookies) {
  // error - <Error>
  // cookies - <PostmanCookieList>
  // PostmanCookieList: https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/CookieList.html
});
```

## get specific cookie

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.get('http://example.com', 'token', function (error, value) {
  // error - <Error>
  // value - <String>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

into Chrome, right click -> Inspect Element. Go to the tab active tracking of resources and if you have not already. Now the left hand sidebar thingy down until you see "Cookies", click below your domain name and to remove a cookie just right-click on it and "Delete"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Postman interceptor.That you can add into the chrome extension by this link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo

This helps you send requests which use browser cookies through the Postman app. 
It can also send headers which are normally restricted by Chrome but are critical for testing APIs.

And also you can enable by interceptor which is there beside the orange sync icon
[image: And also you can enable by interceptor which is there beside the orange sync icon.]

Answer (score 0):

I tried clearing the chrome cookies to get rid of postman cookies, as one of the answers given here. But it didn't work for me. 
I checked my postman version, found that it's an old version 5.5.4.
So I just tried a Postman update to its latest version  7.3.4.
Cool, the issue fixed !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the response of aaron can be enhanced for URL that contains variables:

```
var sdk = require('postman-collection');      

const testURL=pm.environment.values.substitute(pm.request.url, null, false);

const objURL=new sdk.Url(testURL);

console.log("clearing cookies for: "+testURL);

const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.clear(objURL, function (error) {
  // error - <Error>
  if(error)
  console.log("Error clearing cookies: "+error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Clear Cache extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn)? Give it a try. It clears app cache, downloads, file systems, form data, history, local storage, passwords and much more, available in the Options settings.

**Update**: try this answer https://superuser.com/a/232794

I'm not sure of a way to do this in Postman. I used to close the whole browser and reset the server in order to authenticate again. Never tested logout because it was an API service.