# Cookies are being cached when I send a new GET request?

Tags: postman

i'm sending GET requests to my local REST server and I'm trying to set the request Cookie header to something different each time.

however, it seems that postman is somehow caching something because whenever I modify my cookie header request contents to something new it sends the old cookie header request contents.

i have no idea why it doesn't pick up the new cookie header contents that I set.  this is not with interceptor turned on.

Comment: Could you please create a single request collection and share? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sharing . Also, here is a tutorial to check what final request Postman is making - http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/ - you can see if it is being cached or not.

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya thx I'll dig into the troubleshooting docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete session cookie in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305273/how-to-delete-session-cookie-in-postman)