# How can I disable or delete cookies in the Postman application manually

Tags: session, cookies, postman

I am doing some API testing using Postman on Mac OSX.

How can I delete session cookies from the application?

I looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305273/how-to-delete-session-cookie-in-postman), but this solution is for the Postman **Google Chrome extension** and not the application.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Postman v7.23.0.

Go to **Settings** tab for a request and Click **Disable cookie jar** button to be on.

Comment: only an observation is that this "setting" isn't in app setting, but the setting inside the request tab on side Tests tab. Near to the place where you can put the body with jsons

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Postman v6.5.2, but it's been like this for a while. In the application there is a link to the stored Cookies:

[image]

In there you can delete the cookies manually:

[image]

Plus hidden there, is a cross icon that allows you to delete all cookies:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In latest version of postman you can actually do all kind of CRUD operation on cookie. Check this link
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies

Answer (score 1):

I am using the postman application on windows. On the top right, right after the sync button:

[image: Postman windows application snap]