# Postman: How do you delete cookies in the pre-request script?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, postman

All the postman cookie-management answers I've seen refer to either the browser extension (open chrome, delete cookies viz interceptor etc) or with the app, using the UI to manually manage cookies.

I would like to delete certain cookies in my pre-request code as part of scripting my API tests. (delete them programmatically)

The Sandobx API docs mention  `pm.cookies` so I tried

```
if (pm.cookies !== null) {
   console.log("cookies!");
   console.log(pm.cookies);
}
```

But the `pm.cookies` array is empty. Yet in the console, the GET call then passes a cookie.

There's also `postman.getResponseCookies`, which is null (I assume because we're in the pre-request section, not in the test section)

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639513/1916341) suggested calling the postman-echo service to delete the cookie. I haven't investigated this yet, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: (This is specific to the postman app, not the extension, sorry if I wasn't clear)

Comment: If your API has a delete function that you can use for cookies (like postman-echo has), you may build one request to delete them and chain the request you want to execute (via setNextRequest()).

Comment: The answer concerning postman echo is a dead end, cookies are linked to a domain, so your cookie will be linked to yours, not postman-echo, and then won't be deleted. Too bad, it actully deleted the cookie from the cookie manager.

Comment: You may have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie, but if your cookie is set with http_only, you won't be able to access (and remove) it. In my case, it is http_only (sob). Else you can change its date (accessing it in javascript) and set it to yesterday or even -1 could work I think ...

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312

Answer (score 9):

new version now supports that since 2019/08, see more examples here: [Delete cookies programmatically · Issue #3312 · postmanlabs/postman-app-support](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312)

## Prerequisite

Cookie domains to be given programatic access must be [whitelisted](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#whitelisting-domains-for-programmatic-access-of-cookies).

## clear all cookies

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.clear(pm.request.url, function (error) {
  // error - <Error>
});
```

## get all cookies

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.getAll('http://example.com', function (error, cookies) {
  // error - <Error>
  // cookies - <PostmanCookieList>
  // PostmanCookieList: https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/CookieList.html
});
```

## get specific cookie

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.get('http://example.com', 'token', function (error, value) {
  // error - <Error>
  // value - <String>
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that it's necessary to whitelist domain to access cookies: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#whitelisting-domains-for-programmatic-access-of-cookies

Comment: It is worth noting that the `url` that is passed to `jar.get` in this example must include the request path if there is one. It does not need to include any query string, though.

E.g. "https://example.com/subexample"

NOTE that the URL shown here includes "https://", but it's not being displayed. You will need to include the protocol when getting the cookies.

Comment: `jar.clear(pm.request.url...` doesn't work for me. 1) Notice it's an object. I'm not sure `jar.clear()` supports that. 2) I've got environment variables set that build my my request URL. They aren't resolved at the time I access them (before my script) as you can see: `{"path":["{{endpoint.token}}"],"host":["{{base-path}}"],"query":[],"variable":[]}` - note the variable names in the object's properties, eg. `"{{base-path"}}`. I ended up getting my root domain var's value via `pm.environment.get('host')` which works great to clear all cookies for `{{host}}`.

Comment: also to make the scripts work especially for delete include the domains in "Domains Allowlist" so that script can modify it.

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation [pm API reference](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) the `pm.cookie` API is only for the Tests tab, not for the Pre-request Script.

> The following items are available in TEST SCRIPTS only.
>
> pm.cookies
>
> ...

It seems that you will have to stick with this method : [Interceptor Blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/?_ga=2.16173366.1200512055.1505461063-1386594386.1474014497)

Comment: But the Interceptor is restricted to the Chrome plug-in, which will soon be retired, isn't it?

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference indicates pm.cookies is available for native apps now but i also see the same behaviour as the op with the cookie object being empty

Comment: As of this date in 2020, Postman does allow the usage of pm.cookies.jar() in the pre-request scripts, so @aaron's answer seems more appropriate now.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a very late answer, but for my case where I didn't want to use the cookies to start the execution of the collection, I just needed to uncheck the option "Save cookies after the collection run" and check the option "Run collection without using stored cookies" on the Runner panel.

[image]

And then if I want to manage the cookies on my own, I created a first request on the collection and used the Tests tab just to collect the cookies that I wanted and saved them on a variable.

```
pm.environment.set('cookie', pm.cookies.get('csrftoken'))
pm.environment.set('sessionid', pm.cookies.get('sessionid'))
```