# Deleting cookies in postman programmatically

Tags: cookies, postman

I'm using Newman and the native Windows Postman app to test a REST API. It stores the session cookie between requests, allowing me to access information that requires authorization without providing correct authorization. I would like to be able to delete the cookie within the pre-request script section. Is this possible? I know how to delete cookies using the GUI through reading questions such as [How to delete session cookie in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305273/how-to-delete-session-cookie-in-postman) and the official postman documentation but that doesn't help me deal with this issue.

Comment: I'm using a workaround where I set the cookie value into a global variable, and use the variable in the headers of the requests. I then clear them using `postman.setGlobalVariable(VAR_NAME)`, which removes it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Postman v7.6.0 has added support for programmatic cookie access. Hence, if you want to delete a cookie in the pre-request script, you can do the following:

**Remove a single cookie**

```js
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.unset(pm.request.url, 'cookie name', function (error) {
  // handle error
});
```

**Remove all cookies**

```js
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.clear(pm.request.url, function (error) {
  // handle error
});
```

> You can find a detailed overview of the API here:
>   https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#programmatic-accees-of-cookies

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Postman, it's an open feature request at the moment:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312#issuecomment-413750185