# Request entity too large-413 in postman

Tags: jboss, postman, ajp

I'm getting this error when trying to hit a service from postman but not through advanced rest client.Intially, thought it is due to some web cache layer on the server or some postman cookies but when I'm accessing it fails but another colleague access the same service it becomes successful.I'm using desktop application Postman.we are using AJP connections on JBoss server and max packet size and body size are set to max. can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by large request due to many cookies attached to your request, You need to delete the cookies [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305273/how-to-delete-session-cookie-in-postman), which can be done which chrome settings:

> chrome://settings/content/cookies Then go to "See all cookies and site data"

If you are using Native Postman use its Cookie manager

> Native Postman app there is "Cookie manager"

Comment: I'm using desktop version and I have deleted all cookies in postman application, but no luck.